# debootstrap failed, what now?

Tags: debian

I followed this tutorial:
http://www.bitstormweb.com/linux-administration/multiple-versions-of-php-mysql-and-apache-under-debian-linux.html 
When in Step 3 - running debootstrap - my ssh connection got terminated for some reason.
i was able to reconnect but now i have a bootstrap directory in unknown state.

Any idea what i have to do now?
Can i just remove it or is it somehow connected to the rest of the system?

Please Help!
Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `rm -rf /lenny-php53/*` and try again without issues, the debootstrap command limits itself to the destination directory. But just re-running debootstrap without removing the leftovers from the latest run will probably work.

Comment: Looks like re-running worked well :)
Thank you!

Comment: Btw.: Could you recommend any Site/Blog/Whatever on debootstrap, the docs included are pretty thin...
And i really would like to know stuff like: What do i have to do if i reboot the server? Is there something that takes care of whatever is running inside the chrooted bootstrap (?) - because i plan to run a webserver inside...

Comment: Well, debootstrap only helps you with the initial setup of the chrooted environment. The actual functioning has more to do with chroot or virtualization (if you choose to go that way) than with debootstrap. You can create init scripts for whatever services you want to run chrooted - some scripts already sport a parameter $ROOT that lets you use them easily for this. Check http://wiki.freaks-unidos.net/chrooted-debian-server for an example on how to modify a init script.